# IntelliJ MVC Server Context initialization failed

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven

Following a udemy course, I have encountered this issue, to which the answer I didn't find anywhere.

I've had issues with the model class, but that seems to be working now.
URL pattern is fixed, by just being a /
for webmvc i have updated the dependency to be 4.3.6.RELEASE

Code itself and the server was running just before adding changes to the controller, enabling it to pass message value to the model.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**HelloWebServlet.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

   
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.luv2code.springdemo.mvc"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemeLocation="
                    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/HelloWeb-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.luv2code.springweb</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web-demo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>spring-web-demo Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://localhost:8080/spring-web-demo</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
      <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.23</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>spring-web-demo</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

**HelloWorldController**

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {


    @RequestMapping("/showForm")
    public String showForm() {
        return "helloworld-form";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/processForm")
    public String processForm() {
        return "helloworld";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/processFormVersionTwo")
    public String letsShoutDude(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {

        String theName = request.getParameter("studentName");

        theName = theName.toUpperCase();

        String result = "Yo! " + theName;

        model.addAttribute("message", result);

        return "helloworld";
    }

}
```

**The error log**

```
C:\Users\Slimas\.jdks\openjdk-17\bin\java.exe -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\Slimas\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.67 -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Slimas\.SmartTomcat\spring-web-demo\spring-web-demo -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\Slimas\.SmartTomcat\spring-web-demo\spring-web-demo\temp -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\Slimas\.SmartTomcat\spring-web-demo\spring-web-demo\conf\logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=59958:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\Slimas\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.67\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Users\Slimas\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.67\bin\tomcat-juli.jar org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
05-Oct-2022 14:55:37.818 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.67
05-Oct-2022 14:55:37.820 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Sep 23 2022 11:22:29 UTC
05-Oct-2022 14:55:37.820 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.67.0
05-Oct-2022 14:55:37.820 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
05-Oct-2022 14:55:37.820 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
05-Oct-2022 14:55:37.820 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
05-Oct-2022 14:55:37.820 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Users\Slimas\.jdks\openjdk-17
05-Oct-2022 14:55:37.820 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           17+35-2724
05-Oct-2022 14:55:37.821 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
05-Oct-2022 14:55:37.821 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Slimas\.SmartTomcat\spring-web-demo\spring-web-demo
05-Oct-2022 14:55:37.821 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\Slimas\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.67
05-Oct-2022 14:55:37.826 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
05-Oct-2022 14:55:37.826 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
05-Oct-2022 14:55:37.826 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
05-Oct-2022 14:55:37.826 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
05-Oct-2022 14:55:37.826 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
05-Oct-2022 14:55:37.826 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\Slimas\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.67
05-Oct-2022 14:55:37.826 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Slimas\.SmartTomcat\spring-web-demo\spring-web-demo
05-Oct-2022 14:55:37.826 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\Slimas\.SmartTomcat\spring-web-demo\spring-web-demo\temp
05-Oct-2022 14:55:37.826 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\Slimas\.SmartTomcat\spring-web-demo\spring-web-demo\conf\logging.properties
05-Oct-2022 14:55:37.827 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
05-Oct-2022 14:55:37.827 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=59958:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2\bin
05-Oct-2022 14:55:37.827 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
05-Oct-2022 14:55:37.828 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.35] using APR version [1.7.0].
05-Oct-2022 14:55:37.829 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true], UDS [true].
05-Oct-2022 14:55:37.829 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
05-Oct-2022 14:55:37.831 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022]
05-Oct-2022 14:55:37.985 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
05-Oct-2022 14:55:37.998 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [298] milliseconds
05-Oct-2022 14:55:38.023 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
05-Oct-2022 14:55:38.024 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.67]
05-Oct-2022 14:55:38.030 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [C:\Users\Slimas\.SmartTomcat\spring-web-demo\spring-web-demo\conf\Catalina\localhost\spring-web-demo.xml]
05-Oct-2022 14:55:38.939 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
05-Oct-2022 14:55:39.152 INFO [main] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
05-Oct-2022 14:55:39.173 SEVERE [main] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:102)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:628)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1164)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1010)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4958)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5265)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1889)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:583)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:473)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1618)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:946)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:229)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:81)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:51)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:95)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.<init>(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
        ... 51 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.metrics.ApplicationStartup
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1412)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
        ... 62 more
05-Oct-2022 14:55:39.188 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [C:\Users\Slimas\.SmartTomcat\spring-web-demo\spring-web-demo\conf\Catalina\localhost\spring-web-demo.xml] has finished in [1,157] ms
05-Oct-2022 14:55:39.190 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
05-Oct-2022 14:55:39.220 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [1222] milliseconds
http://localhost:8080/spring-web-demo/
```

And lastly, the project structure:[Image of project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLRCJ.png)

Comment: &lt;load-on-startup&gt;-1&lt;/load-on-startup&gt; minus one for start on request, 0 1 2 3 e.t.c. for auto loading on startup in order of loading each servlet.

Comment: Sorry still fairly new, basically my servlet load order is incorrect?

Comment: Only one servlet should either be zero to load on startup first in order or -1 to load when a request call is made. However, the error refers to a missing interface that belongs to an instance instance of org.springframework.core.metrics.jfr.FlightRecorderApplicationStartup class , so check that jar was part of the ide save on compile.

Comment: Never mix versions of jars from a framework. You are mixing jars from Spring 4.3 and 5.3 that won't work.

Comment: M. Deinum, should I remove one then? The tutorials weren't very specific, and jars are a bit tricky

Comment: The versions should match. Ideally you define a version in your `<properties>` section and use that for specific frameworks. Or even better ditch what you have now and move to Spring Boot which will make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

As per advise

```
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
<version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
```

Was changed to:

```
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
<version>5.3.23</version>
```

Now it works.
Cheers!